# When did mail.smtp.password become non-functional?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have the following code for sending email:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "host");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.user", "username");
props.put("mail.smtp.password", "password");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
session.setDebug(true);

Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@example.com"));
msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("to@example.com"));
msg.setSubject("HEY " + new Date());
msg.setContent("This is a test message", "text/plain");
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect();
transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
```

Various sites on the web point to mail.smtp.password being used to pass in a password to Java Mail's SMTP authentication. However, this does not seem to work with JavaMail 1.4.4 and the above code.

Is this something that has been deprecated?

Answer (score 3):

The (latest) [JavaMail javadoc](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) doesn't mention using `mail.smtp.password` a way to specify the password required for authentication. Not sure if it worked earlier. I've always used an `Authenticator` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The `javax.mail.Service` does the `connect()` connecting to the specified host and port. In there, it uses the `javax.mail.Authenticator` for authentication.

The code from `javax.mail.Service.connect()` method:

```
public synchronized void connect(String host, int port,
        String user, String password) throws MessagingException {

    // see if the service is already connected
    if (isConnected())
        throw new IllegalStateException("already connected");

    PasswordAuthentication pw;
    boolean connected = false;
    boolean save = false;
    String protocol = null;
    String file = null;

    // get whatever information we can from the URL
    // XXX - url should always be non-null here, Session
    //       passes it into the constructor
    if (url != null) {
        protocol = url.getProtocol();
        if (host == null)
        host = url.getHost();
        if (port == -1)
        port = url.getPort();

        if (user == null) {
        user = url.getUsername();
        if (password == null)   // get password too if we need it
            password = url.getPassword();
        } else {
        if (password == null && user.equals(url.getUsername()))
            // only get the password if it matches the username
            password = url.getPassword();
        }

        file = url.getFile();
    }

    // try to get protocol-specific default properties
    if (protocol != null) {
        if (host == null)
        host = session.getProperty("mail." + protocol + ".host");
        if (user == null)
        user = session.getProperty("mail." + protocol + ".user");
    }

    // try to get mail-wide default properties
    if (host == null)
        host = session.getProperty("mail.host");

    if (user == null)
        user = session.getProperty("mail.user");

    // try using the system username
    if (user == null) {
        try {
        user = System.getProperty("user.name");
        } catch (SecurityException sex) {
        if (debug)
            sex.printStackTrace(session.getDebugOut());
        }
    }

    // if we don't have a password, look for saved authentication info
    if (password == null && url != null) {
        // canonicalize the URLName
        setURLName(new URLName(protocol, host, port, file, user, null));
        pw = session.getPasswordAuthentication(getURLName());
        if (pw != null) {
        if (user == null) {
            user = pw.getUserName();
            password = pw.getPassword();
        } else if (user.equals(pw.getUserName())) {
            password = pw.getPassword();
        }
        } else
        save = true;
    }

    // try connecting, if the protocol needs some missing
    // information (user, password) it will not connect.
    // if it tries to connect and fails, remember why for later.
    AuthenticationFailedException authEx = null;
    try {
        connected = protocolConnect(host, port, user, password);
    } catch (AuthenticationFailedException ex) {
        authEx = ex;
    }

    // if not connected, ask the user and try again
    if (!connected) {
        InetAddress addr;
        try {
        addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        addr = null;
        }
        pw = session.requestPasswordAuthentication(
                addr, port,
                protocol,
                null, user);
        if (pw != null) {
        user = pw.getUserName();
        password = pw.getPassword();

        // have the service connect again
        connected = protocolConnect(host, port, user, password);
        }
    }

    // if we're not connected by now, we give up
    if (!connected) {
        if (authEx != null)
        throw authEx;
        else if (user == null)
        throw new AuthenticationFailedException(
            "failed to connect, no user name specified?");
        else if (password == null)
        throw new AuthenticationFailedException(
            "failed to connect, no password specified?");
        else
        throw new AuthenticationFailedException("failed to connect");
    }

    setURLName(new URLName(protocol, host, port, file, user, password));

    if (save)
        session.setPasswordAuthentication(getURLName(),
                new PasswordAuthentication(user, password));

    // set our connected state
    setConnected(true);

    // finally, deliver the connection event
    notifyConnectionListeners(ConnectionEvent.OPENED);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware that it was ever functional, and I've been using JavaMail for about ten years. Probably an urban myth. It would be rather a security hole if it really worked. Use the Authenticator interface.